# PDO echo id number into SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

This is the code i use to login a user, i want to get the id number of the user and echo it into $_SESSION['Teacher'] to use later on, i thought you could do it using $row['id'], but it seems not.. any help is appreciated.

```
public function verifyLogin($username, $password){
    // this function checks whether the user name exists and if its a match
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE username=? AND password=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $username);
        $st->bindParam(2, $password);
        $st->execute();

        if ($st->rowCount() == 1){

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['Teacher'] = $row['id'];

            header("Location: dashboard.php");

        } else {

            header("Location: login.php?incorrect");
        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: Does your table `teachers` contain a row `id`? And have you checked this: `print_r($row);`? Sorry, I see you haven't even retrieved the row. You should use `PDOStatement::fetch()` to do this.

Comment: `session_start` in the function's body?

Comment: There's any number of things that could be wrong.  You failed to indicate what makes you think there's something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is not being set anywhere. You have to call `$st->fetch()` to fetch the first row and then the assignment to `$_SESSION['Teacher']` should work.

Comment: Using.. `$st->fetch($row['id'])` when i echo out `$_SESSION['Teacher']` i'm just getting `Array`

Comment: `$row = $st->fetch();` is what you're looking for.

Comment: i don't understand where that would go

Comment: Replace your code inside the if clause with this:

    `session_start();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $_SESSION['Teacher'] = $row['id'];

    header("Location: dashboard.php");`